# complex multipart clickable label on dc.js bar chart

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

I am new to dc.js. I want to build the chart pictured below:

[image]

On the top of each bar, there should be values like 2/3. This denotes the number of records for two different categories. I need to show each value in a different color.

Also I have a requirement that the values should be clickable to view the records in separate table when we click on the value.

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: I looked at this. The bar chart does support labels, but you’d have to replace them in order to have multiple `tspan` with different colors and (I presume) different links for the different colors. I couldn’t find any good way to modify the current labels. It’s possible to do this using event handlers and D3 but it’s not easy.